# Does PyCharm support type hinting for globals?

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

I've tried setting my global in a python_stub as follows:

```
#Inside MyModule.pyi
global MY_GLOBAL #type: list[MyClass]
```

However, this doesn't seem to work when I try to index into my global list in the main .py file:

```
#Back inside MyModule.py
MY_GLOBAL[0].xyz #<-- Expecting type hinting to pop up after the '.'
```

Also, I've tried doing this without python_stub files as follows:

```
#Inside MyModule.py
MY_GLOBAL #type: list[MyClass]

#Still in the global scope here
MY_GLOBAL[0].xyz #<-- Type hinting works here!
```

When I do this (setting the type locally), it recognizes the type in the global scope, however, as soon as I try to use the global in a function scope, it forgets the type:

```
#Inside MyModule.py
MY_GLOBAL #type: list[MyClass]

#Still in the global scope here
MY_GLOBAL[0].xyz #<-- Type hinting works here!

def MyFunction():
    global MY_GLOBAL
    MY_GLOBAL[0].xyz #<-- Expecting type hinting to pop up after the '.'
```

Does anyone know if this behaviour is supported?  I'm using PyCharm 5.0 Community Edition.

Comment: The headline is not related to the actual problem as answered here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a problem with type hinting. The problem is that you don't actually have a `MY_GLOBAL` variable at all.

`global MY_GLOBAL` isn't how you make a global variable. There's no such thing* as a truly-global variable in Python. You make a module-level global variable the same way you make a local variable:

```
MY_GLOBAL = []
```

but at module level instead of within a function. If you want to access it from another module, you need to import the module and use dotted access notation:

```
import whichever_module_defined_the_global as m

m.MY_GLOBAL.append(3)
```

Trying to import it with a `from` import will cause weird problems, so don't do that.

<sup>*Aside from stuff like `max` or `open`.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think I may have typo'd that first line.  It should have been simply MY_GLOBAL = [], as you described.  I actually managed to solve my issue, however.  I had to remove the reference to "global" in the local function scope where I wanted type-hinting.

Comment: actually, `max` and `open` etc. aren't global either, the thing is the module `__builtins__` gets imported (and adds its contents to the global scope like `globals()['thing'] = thing`) every time the interpreter starts unless it's passed the `-S` switch.

Comment: @ocket8888: No, that's not how it works. The module is `builtins` or `__builtin__`, and it doesn't dump its contents into `globals()`; it's used as a fallback when a name isn't found in module-globals. Under the hood, frame objects have an `f_builtins` member storing their global variable dict, which is set using either another frame's `f_builtins` or the `__builtins__` global variable, and `__builtins__` is usually set to either the `builtins`/`__builtin__` module or that module's dict.

Comment: Also, `-S` has no effect on the built-in variable fallback; it disables auto-importing of the `site` module.